# How do I connect an audio worklet to a web page?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audio-worklet

I'm trying to connect a web page to an audio worklet (following this [demos](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/web-audio-samples/audio-worklet/basic/hello-audio-worklet/) but I got stuck.

Can somebody help?

Here's the code I've got so far.
Those files are all in the same folder, but they don't log anything.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
const demoCode = async () => {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext()
    await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('test-processor.js')
    const testNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'test-processor')
    testNode.connect(audioContext.destination)
  }
```

**TEST-PROCESSOR.JS**

```
class TestProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  constructor () {
    super()
    console.log(currentFrame)
    console.log(currentTime)
  }
  process (inputs, outputs, parameters) {
    return true
  }
}

console.log(sampleRate)

const usefulVariable = 42
console.log(usefulVariable)

registerProcessor('test-processor', TestProcessor)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not invoking your `demoCode()` function anywhere. If you want to be compliant with the autoplay policy in todays browsers that needs to happen in response to a user gesture.

First you need to add a button to your HTML.

```
<button id="start" type="button">start</button>
```

Then you can attach an event listener for that button within your `index.js` file.

```
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', demoCode);
```

Comment: I solved it by adding on index.html ```<button onclick="demoCode()"></button>```. Still, what I wonder is why it console log the same values, every time I hit the button.

Comment: I guess this is because you create a new AudioContext on each button click. It will always start at 0. You can create a global AudioContext and then call resume() inside of your click handler to resume it in case it was suspended before.